# Expand and combine power query

Tags: excel, api, powerbi, powerquery

I am creating an Excel spreadsheet that gives real time information about an entered stock. This is done through the use of an API request in Power Query.

```
Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=" & #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Column1]))
```

[image: Power Query custom fields] When I expand this tab it separates the records into different columns.[image: Expanded custom column] Is it possible to combine all the separated columns into one column?

Comment: I guess first separate and then merge them.. You will find many sources for merging power query columns on web search. like [this](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=merge+two+columns+in+power+query&view=detail&mid=64E34314F6649B17541264E34314F6649B175412&FORM=VIRE)

Comment: @Naresh how do I combine a record and a null -> record?

Comment: What is your logic? Do you only have the 2 columns and when there is a null, it needs to be filled with the other column value?

Comment: @joey First, expand the "Record" column by clicking the arrows on the top of the column..  Then merge the resulting columns ..  I think we cannot merge the records directly.

Comment: Unpivot the columns with `record` will put all the records into a single column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the following to your scenario from line 20 onwards

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText("i45WclSK1YlWclKKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), 
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ), 
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [Column1 = _t]
  ), 
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Column1", type text}}), 
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "Custom", 
    each [First = "First", Second = "Second"]
  ), 
  #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Added Custom", 
    "Custom.1", 
    each 
      let
        x = [Custom], 
        L = Record.ToList(x), 
        Loop = List.Generate(
          () => [i = 0, j = 0, k = {L{0}}, comb = "0"], 
          each [i] < List.Count(L), 
          each [i = [i] + 1, j = i, k = {L{j}}, comb = Text.Combine(List.Combine({[k], k}), ",")], 
          each [comb]
        ), 
        c = Loop{List.Count(Loop) - 1}
      in
        c
  ), 
  #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom"})
in
  #"Removed Columns"
```